# selecting columns with special characters

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a situation where I have a column called Spy%C. THis is easily accessed with df["Spy%C"] but I get a parse error when trying to do df.Spy%C . Additionally, when I try to regress the column using StatsModels.formula.api, I get a parse error as well with the following code.

```
result = sm.ols(formula='Spy%C ~ SpyVol%C', data=df).fit()
print result.summary()
```

What is the proper format for dealing with this?

Comment: try `Q` http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/v0.2.1/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q  but I'm not sure it works with `%`. If it doesn't work, then you might have to clean your names.

Comment: See the warning down a bit [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access)

Answer (score 0):

`df.Spy%C` in python means `df.Spy.__mod__(C)`, you can't use that mode of address for columns which aren't identifiers. So if you *have* to have a column named `'Syp%C'`, just address it with `df['Syp%C']`.